# Very slow requests to dynamodb from lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have lambda function and dynamo db table in the same region (us-east-1). In lambda function I perform very simple query:

```
params =
  TableName: 'users'
  Item:
    email:
      S: event.body.email
  ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists (email)'
dynamodb.putItem(params, context.done)
```

There are only few rows in DynamoDB table, there is Hash Key on email and Read/Write throughtputs are set to 5/5.

Lambda function exeutes in ~4 seconds... This is very slow. Am I doing something wrong?

---

I've tested my function with different memory settings for lambda function (it was set to 128mb previously):

- 256mb => ~2000ms
- 512mb => ~1000ms
- 1024mb => ~500ms
- 1536mb => ~300ms

So it seems that response time depends 1-1 on memory (well in fact on compute capacity as AWS scales it along with memory). Still this is crazy because to make very simple REST API I have to set 1536mb memory to make it "responsive" while my program uses 17mb!

---

Hmm on the other hand I've calculated that it will cost:

- 8.32$ per 1 milion 4000ms requests using 128mb memory
- 10.004$ per 1 milion 300ms requests using 1536mb memory

So it's not so bad I guess...

Comment: Are you sure that you are not doing anything else in your Lambda function? Simple JS call should not need that much memory and shouldn't take that much time.

Comment: Just for the sake of comparison, what sort of performance do you get if you hit SimpleDB?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am facing a similar issue, I am using batch writes in my lambda function and its taking way too long. Also, the function hardly uses 80MB memory, so increasing the memory to get better performance doesn't seem quite right to me.

Comment: For what it's worth; the Lambda config dialog states "Your function is allocated CPU proportional to the memory configured" - looks like AWS also give you more CPU when you configure more memory...

Comment: I'm doing a simple lookup from a table with 5 entries using the index. I'm getting 16 sec response times with 128MB RAM! adding more ram decreases the latency proportionally too but this is still huge latency!

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem might also be related to un-pausing the container the `Lambda` function is running at. You also may want to optimize how you initialize your objects so they don't get re-initialized every time the function is called.

See the article [Container reuse in Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/).

Comment: Interesting. But what I am doing is only requiring 'aws-sdk' module and sending request to database. I also tried makeing many requests one after another to ensure container is reused...

Comment: The delays you're describing are very large. It also might be the `us-east-1` heavily utilized region.

Comment: I will try out deploying function in other regions.

Comment: I've tested it in "eu-west-1" region (both Lambda and DynamoDB function) and it is the same - with 1536mb memory (max) it takes 300ms for lambda function to execute. Also without the DynamoDB code (single putItem request) it executes in 10ms so the overhead is caused by calling DynamoDB... - and 300ms it just a Lambda function time - If called by HTTP endpoint (API Gateway) it takes 500-600ms...

Comment: We've just started with AWS Lambdas and API Gateway using eu-west and have found the same serious performance problems just calling putItem from a minimal Lambda. I hope this can be fixed as like the OP I don't think there's much else we can do to optimise our code... Unless we can avoid a connection overhead, though gets are fine, which suggests that's not the issue.

Comment: I am using Lambda with DDB and facing the same problem. The get_item() call takes ~200ms to finish, far far more slower than what AWS claimed as "in single-digit ms"!

Comment: @Z.Wei Did you try bumping the Lambda memory? That will also give you more performance.

Comment: @kixorz You are right, I googled and found this solution and tried it with 3008 MB, the performance improved a lot (6x).